# Catch a newly added Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I was wondering if there is any way to catch a 'Project add' event. I know you can do that with the `DTE` e.g. `SolutionEvents.ProjectAdded` event. However I am trying to accomplish this without the use of the `DTE`. I already tried it with the [`IVsHierarchyEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchyevents?view=visualstudiosdk-2017), sadly the `OnItemAdded` and `OnItemsAppended` methods never get called for added Projects.

Note that I want to catch Projects which are either direct children of the solution or a solution-folder.

Comment: DIid you try [IVsSolution Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution?view=visualstudiosdk-2019)?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I am not quite sure how the `IVsSolution` interface should help?

Comment: When you add a project, you can just use [AddVirtualProject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.addvirtualproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2019).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I don't want to add a new project, I want to get notified if a project gets added by a user or another extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SolutionEvents.ProjectAdded is the best way to do this as far as I can tell. Sometimes (not always), but sometimes there aren't more appropriate lower level APIs or interfaces that provide the same or similar functionality found in the EnvDTE automation interfaces. In this particular instance the SolutionEvents ProjectAdded event isn't built upon a lower level API or service, and it's the only event I could find that fits what you're looking for here.

Sincerely,

Comment: I was already guessing something like this, at least in this not an additional layer on top. Thanks though.